# "…that enriches people's everyday life" or "…that enrich people's everyday life"

Tags: grammar

What is correct:

"…that **enriches** people's everyday life"

or

"…that **enrich** people's everyday life"

Comment: *That* is a pronoun indicating a third person, as it were (i.e. not you or the person you are talking to). So you use the third person form of the verb.

Comment: The conjugation of [enrich](http://en.bab.la/conjugation/english/enrich) can be plural or singular depending on what the thing is (he/she/it enriches or they enrich): *Cake that enriches people's everyday life is awesome!* or *Cakes that enrich people's everyday life are awesome!*

Comment: @aediaλ, that's true. I hadn't thought about it in such a way

Answer (score 3):

Both could be correct, depending on the subject. Is whatever is doing the enriching plural or singular? Either way your verb "to enrich" needs to match. If it's a singular noun, then the verb will need to be singular. If it's a plural noun, same thing.

Two examples:

*"The internet is a technology that **enriches** people's everyday life."*

Here **technology** is singular, thus you would use the form **enriches**.

*What are some other examples of technologies that **enrich** people's everyday life?*

In this sentence I used the plural of technology, **technologies**, so I use the verb form **enrich** to match.

Answer (score 1):

The first supposes that what went before is singular. The second supposes that what went before is plural.